# JAXB2 maven plugin in eclipse shows error

Tags: xsd, jaxb, pom.xml, maven-jaxb2-plugin, jaxb2-simplify-plugin

I'm using JDK 1.6 (due to dependencies) and to generate classes from xsd, I have added maven-jaxb2 plugin as shown below in pom.xml.

But the eclipse (Kepler) complains as below.

> Error parsing the command line [[-Xsimplify, -episode,
>   D:\test\workspace\sample\target\generated-sources\xjc\META-INF\sun-jaxb.episode]]
>   (org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.8.1:generate:jaxb-test:generate-sources)

pom.xml

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.0</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>jaxb-test</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>generate</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                    <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                    <schemaIncludes>
                        <include>sample.xsd</include>
                    </schemaIncludes>
                    <xjbSources>
                        <xjbSource>bindings.xjb</xjbSource>
                    </xjbSources>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <extension>true</extension>
            <args>
                <arg>-Xsimplify</arg>
            </args>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                    <version>0.6.0</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Try to upgrade to `maven-jaxb2-plugin` 0.13.1, and `jaxb2-basics` 0.11.0. The versions you have now are very old already.

Comment: Thanks that solved the eclipse pom.xml error. However i still find the generated class has aorB.

Comment: @lexicore could you please have look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704757/jaxb2-simplify-plugin-elements-not-simplified)

Comment: Well, this is another error, another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to upgrade to `maven-jaxb2-plugin` `0.13.1`, and `jaxb2-basics` `0.11.0`.

The versions you have now are very old already.