# jaxb2 simplify plugin elements not simplified

Tags: xsd, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin, jaxb2-simplify-plugin

I have tried to convert XSD to JAXB classes using mave-jaxb2 plugin and jaxb2-basics simplify plugin.

The configuration in pom.xml is available in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676734/jaxb2-maven-plugin-in-eclipse-shows-error)

**sample.xsd (complex choice type)**

```
<xs:complexType name="doclist">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="document1" type="type1">
                    <xs:annotation>
                        <xs:appinfo>
                            <simplify:as-reference-property/>
                        </xs:appinfo>
                    </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="document2" type="type2">
                </xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="heading" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:complexType>
```

However the generated JAXB classes have aOrB references.

```
   @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name = "document1", type = Type1.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "document2", type = Type2.class)
    })
    protected List<Object> document1OrDocument2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an `elements` property so you have to place your annotation on the `xs:choice`, not on the `xs:element`. Please see [the documentation](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/wiki/JAXB2-Simplify-Plugin#simplifying-elements-property).

And you most probably want to use `<simplify:as-element-property/>`.

Comment: Thanks. Does simplify will not work if i have same types for more than one elements ? like `<xs:element name="document1" type="xs:string"> <xs:element name="document2" type="xs:string"> <xs:element name="document3" type="xs:string">`

Comment: @ulab This is another question.

Comment: fine :). I have created another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34860485/jaxb2-simplify-plugin-for-xschoice-having-same-types)