# jaxb2 simplify plugin for xs:choice having same types

Tags: jaxb2-maven-plugin, jaxb2-basics, jaxb2-simplify-plugin

I'm trying to use jaxb2 basics simplify plugin for my schema to JAXB conversion.
It works fine for the complex types like below. Each element is defined inside the `xs:choice` has different types (`type1` and `type2`).

**sample.xsd (complex choice type with different type)**

```
<xs:complexType name="doclist">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                    <simplify:as-element-property />
                </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:element name="document1" type="type1" />
            <xs:element name="document2" type="type2" />
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="heading" type="xs:string" />
</xs:complexType>
```

But if the complex type contains more than one element with same type (`xs:string`), as shown below, then maven install throws error.

**sample.xsd (complex choice type with same type)**

```
<xs:complexType name="addressTEST">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                <simplify:as-element-property />
            </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element name="street" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

Does **jaxb2 simplify** will not work if I have same types for more than one elements ?

```
[ERROR] Error while parsing schema(s).Location [ file:/D:/workspace/trunk/sampmes/src/main/resources/sample.xsd{1099,38}].
com.sun.istack.SAXParseException2: compiler was unable to honor this as-element-property customization. It is attached to a wrong place, or its inconsistent with other bindings.
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ErrorReceiver.error(ErrorReceiver.java:82)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.ErrorReporter.error(ErrorReporter.java:79)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.UnusedCustomizationChecker.check(UnusedCustomizationChecker.java:144)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.UnusedCustomizationChecker.check(UnusedCustomizationChecker.java:122)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.UnusedCustomizationChecker.modelGroup(UnusedCustomizationChecker.java:220)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.ModelGroupImpl.visit(ModelGroupImpl.java:125)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.UnusedCustomizationChecker.particle(UnusedCustomizationChecker.java:241)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.ParticleImpl.visit(ParticleImpl.java:124)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.UnusedCustomizationChecker.complexType(UnusedCustomizationChecker.java:182)
    at com.sun.xml.xsom.impl.ComplexTypeImpl.visit(ComplexTypeImpl.java:295)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.UnusedCustomizationChecker.run(UnusedCustomizationChecker.java:108)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.UnusedCustomizationChecker.run(UnusedCustomizationChecker.java:98)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BGMBuilder._build(BGMBuilder.java:187)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.reader.xmlschema.BGMBuilder.build(BGMBuilder.java:116)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.annotateXMLSchema(ModelLoader.java:415)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:167)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.ModelLoader.load(ModelLoader.java:113)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_1.XJC21Mojo.loadModel(XJC21Mojo.java:50)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_1.XJC21Mojo.doExecute(XJC21Mojo.java:40)
    at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_1.XJC21Mojo.doExecute(XJC21Mojo.java:28)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:505)
    at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.execute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:328)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work, but try customizing one of the `xs:element`s instead.

Depending on the property type produced, you'll need to customize either `xs:choice` or one of the child `xs:elements`.

If you get an "elements" property, customize `xs:choice`. See [the documentation](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/wiki/JAXB2-Simplify-Plugin#simplifying-elements-property). This is what you have in the first case.

If you get an "element references" property, customize one of the `xs:elements`. See [the documentation](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics/wiki/JAXB2-Simplify-Plugin#simplifying-references-property). This is what you have in the second case.

Comment: great! thanks. it worked. Although i dont understand why JAXB generates XMLElementRef sometimes and XMLelement sometimes.

Comment: If you have different types then JAXB can infer the element name from the type. If you have different elements with the same type then it's not possible and JAXB has to use `@XmlElementRef` property.